# Validating the user of an access_token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-authorization

In the Facebook dev article [Manually Building a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow), there is a section entitled "Confirming Identity". It mentions that you need to validate codes and tokens that you receive from them via your `redirect_uri`.

**My question**: Since you don't know anything about the user that just logged in, how do you validate that the `user_id` that you see in the response from the [token inspection endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/#checktoken) is correct?

The article says:

> As a result, your app should confirm that the person using the app is the same person that you have response data for before generating an access token for them.

But, how can you actually do that? Are we expected to show publicly available info about that `user_id` back to the user with a UI that asks "Is this you?". I haven't seen any apps/sites that do that, so I'm assuming that this isn't practically done.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) to retrieve information about the logged in user. It returns a response object for the user. If the user has authenticated your application, the response object will look like this:

```
{
    status: 'connected',
    authResponse: {
        accessToken: '...',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest:'...',
        userID:'...'
    }
}
```

You can use the UserId returned in this object to verify the user's identity.